# FDCE flip-flop primitive in Altera Quartus?

Tags: fpga, xilinx, intel-fpga, spartan, cyclone

I would like to know the Altera Quartus primitive equivalent to the FDCE flip-flop on Xilinx ISE.

I think that the DFFE primitive might work, however, I am not sure about the CE and CLR pins equivalency; also the PRN pin confuse me.

Here's a [link](http://quartushelp.altera.com/14.1/mergedProjects/hdl/prim/prim_pu_pinstub_names.htm) to the Altera documentation that I have been using so far.

[image]

Comment: Why do you need a primitive? Can't you write it as portable, generic VHDL or Verilog code?

Comment: I am pretty sure that will be a right solution. But at this point I am trying to map features between the two IDEs for educational reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Newer versions of Quartus have wrappers for different basic flip-flop types. A list of all primitives can be found here: [Primitive List for Quartus 15](http://quartushelp.altera.com/15.0/mergedProjects/hdl/prim/prim_list.htm)

Here is the DFFE component:

```
COMPONENT DFFE
  PORT (
    d    : IN  STD_LOGIC;   -- Data input
    clk  : IN  STD_LOGIC;   -- Clock
    clrn : IN  STD_LOGIC;   -- Clear (Reset, low-active)
    prn  : IN  STD_LOGIC;   -- Preset (low-active)
    ena  : IN  STD_LOGIC;   -- (Clock) Enable
    q    : OUT STD_LOGIC    -- Data output
  );
END COMPONENT;
```

Source: http://quartushelp.altera.com/15.0/mergedProjects/hdl/prim/prim_file_dffe.htm

---

**Outdated Altera documentation:**

There is the Quartus [Low Level Primitive Guide](https://www.altera.com/en_US/pdfs/literature/ug/ug_low_level.pdf).

Here is the basic flip-flop cell:

```
COMPONENT DFFEAS
  PORT (
    d      : IN  STD_LOGIC;
    clk    : IN  STD_LOGIC;
    clrn   : IN  STD_LOGIC;
    prn    : IN  STD_LOGIC;
    ena    : IN  STD_LOGIC;
    asdata : IN  STD_LOGIC;
    aload  : IN  STD_LOGIC;
    sclr   : IN  STD_LOGIC;
    sload  : IN  STD_LOGIC;
    q      : OUT STD_LOGIC
  );
END COMPONENT;
```

Quartus has only one primitive, whereas Xilinx offers different wrappers for the same primitive.